# How to add a AWS RDS database to amplify

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-rds, aws-amplify

I am currently working with amplify and GraphQL instance which is fairly simple. I then realised that I need to use things like `sum()` `average() etc as I am building a football website which uses a lot of stats and writing custom resolvers for all of this will be too much work.

So I have created a Aurora MySQL database and am trying to add it. It is hosted in Region `eu-west-2` but it will not come up when trying to add it:

```
hutber@hutber:/var/www/unsal.co.uk$ amplify api add-graphql-datasource
Using datasource: Aurora Serverless, provided by: awscloudformation
? Provide the region in which your cluster is located: 
  us-east-1 
  us-east-2 
  us-west-2 
  ap-northeast-1 
❯ eu-west-1
```

I believe by adding MySQL I will be able to then query this MySQL instance via my GQL service.

Answer (score 0):

By upgrading amplify to the latest version this issue was fixed:

```
amplify -v: 4.29.4
```